How can I find recently created Entries in Apple calendar?
I just created an entry in the calendar for today but now I don't see this entry in the calendar. I think I might have entered the date incorrectly, so therefore the entry is not visible in todays view, week or month.
Is there any way to get calendar entries by creation time so I can fix this error?
I am open to any suggestions. Following systems are available for a solution:

macos Sonoma
iPadOS 17
iOS 17


Use shortcuts app on any of your chosen OS to find calendar items by modified date. If you want to change modified to creation date, that’s available as well.

Adjust the last modified, date range and/or limit if you get too few or many results.

Thanks for your creative answer, it really looks promising. The link in your answer is icing on the cake. Unfortunatley when I press the play button to run the shortcut, I dont see any result. I never used shortcuts, should I look for something that takes the result and shows it somehow? What do you see when you run the shortcut?

No results means you didn’t have a match. Make a new event and try again @Human. Where are your calendars stored? iCloud? On device? Gmail? Other sync? Hopefully you didn’t make an event more than 7 years in advance or ago.

I did create a new event, still no results were shown. I am using icloud to sync my calendars.

I’m not sure how your test event  is escaping the conditions - I’ll assume you created a normal event and it shows properly in calendar. I can use my automation on iPad and two different iPhones and it works well for me and shows lots of results if I increase the duration of last modified.
